# Pass an @interface to a 'data' class, then display the field 'getName()'

Tags: java, generics, interface

I've got a class like so:

```
class Data<T extends Annotation> {
    public Data(T annotation) {
        for (Field f : annotation.getClass().getFields()) {
            ...println(f.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass an @interface to it. Example's sake, let's say my interface is the following:

```
@Retention(..RUNTIME)
@interface foo {
    int bar() default 0;
}
```

This is the class which will have the annotation:

```
@foo(bar = 15) // bar is now 15
public class someClass {
    public Data<foo> d = new Data<foo>(getClass().getAnnotation(foo.class)); // should pass the 15 along as well
}
```

The problem seems to be at annotation.getClass().getFields(). It won't return any valid fields, which then will not loop, which won't print the names out. Am I trying to access the fields incorrectly? I can't see any other options inside of T which could let me grab fields, so what might be wrong?

Comment: What precisely is the responsibility of your `Data` class? In most cases like this, you'd need to pass in `someClass.class`, not `foo.class` (and remember to capitalize type names).

Comment: As it stands now, it's merely a proof of concept. The plan is to make this find all fields, create a clone of them inside of a hashmap, and push the hashmap publicly to access these fields and even modify them, since instances cannot be modified

Answer (score 1):

I've found I'm accessing it wrong. It seems that @interfaces consider their values as methods instead, specifically declaredMethods. So, in other to access them, I need to iterate `annotation.annotationType().getDeclaredMethods()` instead